# Renaming Xcode Header and Implementation files

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I was wondering if, in Xcode, it was possible to find and change all references to the name of a header file, and chage it with something else and still have it work, what I mean is find a name like this: [image], and have it find all references to it like this: [image], and this: [image] and replace them with the new name. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename a class with the "Refactor" function in Xcode:

- Select the class name "BlueJaysViewController" in "@implementation BlueJaysViewController".
- Choose Edit -> Refactor -> Rename ...
- Enter the new class name and select "Rename related files"

Comment: Then it gives me this error: `ClassTwoVideoOne.m is not part of the build phase of any targets in this workspace and so can’t be refactored`

Comment: @Alan: Yes, what I described works if the to-be-renamed class is part of the target (which is normally the case). Can't you add the .m file to the target?

Comment: It says it already is added in the Build Phases tab, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @Alan: Select the file and check the "Target Membership" in the "File Inspector". - Do you have more than one target?

Comment: this is wrong answer